# How to bind to one property of an existing collection of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application. I have a collection of objects that have several properties that are already set, with one property that needs to be set. I'm unsure of how to go about binding an input to that one property while maintaining the existing values for the other properties.

I've seen resources on how to model bind to a complex collection, but I don't think that approach will work since that seems to create a new instance of the object type and I want to be able to do this with my existing collection of objects. EDIT: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Ex.

```cs
List<MyObject> objectList;

class MyObject {
   public int propertyA { get; set; }
   public int propertyB { get; set; }
   public int propertyC { get; set; }
}
```

In the context of the above example, I want to bind my input to the objectList collection, but I only want to bind to propertyC (at some other point in time, propertyA and propertyB for all of these objects was already established)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just down to what you name the input; it needs to be in the form of `CollectionProperty[N].PropertyC`, where `N` is the index. Assuming you're both binding to `List<MyObject>` and using that as your view's model:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="@Model[i].PropertyC" />
}
```

Which would correspond to an action param like:

```
public IActionResult Foo(List<MyObject> myObjects)
```

However, I think what you're *actually* struggling with is that fact that your "existing" collection doesn't actually exist. Each request is unique, and the only things that exist are things that were literally sent along with that request. The fact that you populated the view initially with some collection of things is inconsequential. Unless you post back that full collection, it no longer exists.

Not that you *should* post it back. Anything that is posted can potentially be modified, and if you don't want `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` to be modified, they should not be posted. So where does that leave you? Mapping.

What you want to do is post just `PropertyC` for all the items. Then, you fetch your fully populated list of `MyObject` instances however you go about that (query database, etc.). Then, you iterate over one list or the other, and map over the value of `PropertyC` to your fully populated list:

```
for (var i = 0; i < existingMyObjects.Count; i++)
{
    existingMyObjects[i].PropertyC = myObjects[i].PropertyC;
}
```

FWIW, you might also want to post an associate ID or similar. The method above relies on collection order being the same both before and after, which is not always guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I didn't end up needing to use an associate ID, but just out of curiosity, how would that work if I didn't want to allow the user to provide that ID? Can I supply my own data to be posted along with the user's input?

Comment: You can use a hidden input, but it would still have to be part of the form and posted along with everything else. That does mean that the user could alter the id using developer tools in the browser, if they really wanted to, but there's no much you can do about that. Generally speaking, that shouldn't be much of an issue in this particular instance, as there's very little to gain by fudging ids here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach to bind data to propertyC, like that:

```
foreach (var item in objectList)
{
    item.propertyC = 50; //Bind the value that you want
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've specified that the input will be coming from a html form. So when a post request gets sent, I want to automatically bind only to propertyC. Similar to this: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: @user9997229: Yeah! It's Ok. You're always welcome, my friend :D